# Mailserver different in database than the wp dashboard

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp, admin, phpmailer

My mail is working properly in my site and while i was looking at the database and my cpanel i see some weird stuff.. I think tha mailserver should be the same everywhere right? But why in my database is like that and not the one I change in dashboard? Should i change that manually or not?

Please look at mailserver_url and login..
[image]

[image]

And thats my dashboard..

Also last but not least... Should my dns have all this diff IPs?
[image]

I think i get lost a little bit here.. Any feedback what should i change?I get a lot of Timed-Out 504 error when trying to use my forms.. Could these setting be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using fast hosts change your webmail from xxxxxxx.231 to xxxxxxx.229